# Rails 5.0 - cucumber-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I am having trouble trying to install `cucumber-rails` gem on Rails 5.0. It throws the following error:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed
(https://rubygems.org/gems/addressable-2.4.0.gem)

An error occurred while installing addressable (2.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install addressable -v '2.4.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

gem install addresssable then throws a gem not found error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the gem source from

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

in  your top of the Gemfile.

Comment: Got around it by manually replacing the CA certificate manually!